# i call wcf with window service this time not work ClientCredentials

Tags: c#, wcf

whenewer user add own ClientCredentials and access file this time throw exception file not access but user all right apply to this file \pareshweb1.in.paresh.com\ADPTest\PareshTest.txt

please give me any other way to apply credential and access my file.

```
//this code call to wcf hosted in window services

  //use ChannelFactory
            string url = "net.tcp://localhost:8733/Service1";

            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding()
            {
                OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue / 8,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue / 8,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,

                ListenBacklog = 100,
                MaxConnections = 100,
            };


            //binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;

            ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(
                binding, url);

            var defaultCredentials = factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
            factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials);

            ClientCredentials loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
            loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = "ram";
            loginCredentials.UserName.Password = "test@123";
            factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials);

            //inject endpoint behavior
            //factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new SimpleEndpointBehavior());

            IService1 client = factory.CreateChannel();
```

---

over wcf method logic

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        private string logPath = @"C:\TEMP\TestLog.txt";

        //[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteInfoLog("File Write Start");
                File.AppendAllText(@"\\pareshweb1.in.paresh.com\ADPTest\PareshTest.txt","file Write Sucess");

                WriteInfoLog("File Write End");

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                WriteErrorLog(ex);
            }

            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        #region Log Write

        private void WriteInfoLog(string str)
        {
            try
            {

                File.AppendAllText(logPath, str + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                File.AppendAllText(logPath, ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }

        private void WriteErrorLog(Exception exception)
        {
            try
            {
                File.AppendAllText(logPath, exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                File.AppendAllText(logPath, ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }

        #endregion
    }
```

whenwer call wcf service this time throw bellow error

Access to the path '\pareshweb1.in.paresh.com\ADPTest\PareshTest.txt' is denied.

Comment: //call service
        

            string repObj = client.GetData(10);

Comment: is it network credentials

Comment: yes and folder share with specifi credentials

Answer (score 0):

The network share directory requires credential instead of the account which hosts the WCF service.  We could exclude the issue by writing the file the local file directory. I don’t think we could specify the credential to access the directory located in the network except that the computer(server host) has stored the credential to access the network share directory.
In windows, it located in the Control Panel>Credential Manager.
Besides, the above client credential is provided for the server authenticates the client other than the account for the network share directory.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.